# plugin not found in cordova application

Tags: javascript, ios, ios4, cordova-2.0.0

In my ios project, I need native AlertView by using Cordova cordova-1.9.0.js.

I have checked that link:   [native AlertView](http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-use-the-native-alert-dialog-in-phonegap)

I have checked   [cordova documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert)

In this I have added required permission also in App/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist

```
   <key>Plugins</key>
     <dict>
        <key>Notification</key>
        <string>CDVNotification</string>
     </dict>
```

But while running it is giving me this error

> ERROR: Plugin '' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.

It is not showing the alert to me.

I am not sure where to find out from ? Please suggest me where I went wrong ?
Is there any problem related to that version of cordova ?

Answer (score 0):

The `navigator.notification` is part of Cordova core so you don't need to add another entry to cordova.plist. There should already be an entry. Remove your entry and try again.

Comment: After removing that permission from cordova.plist, same error is coming.

Comment: My html page is exactly same as cordova documentation html page.In that you can find javascript. You can visit that link.